# UINavigationController Layout Broken after Presenting Modal

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios5, uinavigationbar, modalviewcontroller, statusbar

Ever since iOS5, I have a problem where when I present and then dismiss a modal view, my Navigation Controller bar is hidden underneath the status bar.   I have read the forums and tried many things but I cannot find the fix for this behavior.

Also, I get this behavior when presenting any modal view controller so it does not appear to be specific to the view controller I am presenting.  At first I thought it was a problem with ZXing but this seems to be generic with the iOS5 update.

Additionally, if I select a UITextField after dismissing the modal and my navigation bar is hidden under the status bar, the keyboard comes up misplaced in my window.   Again, if I do a rotate back and forth, the navigation controller bar and the keyboard work just fine.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

**RESOLVED**
OK.  I finally found the problem here.  Again this only appeared in iOS5 but when my RootViewController launches it holds off on rotations until the animation is done.  Once it is done, then it allows rotations again.   The problem was that it was returning NO for all aspects (including portrait).  The view showed fine but when I would present a modal and return, the view geometry was mangled.  Once I changed it to return YES for portrait mode even during animation, the problem went away.

Comment: Hi, could you please provide more information about how you solved it? I have the exact same issue and haven't had any luck playing around with the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method.

Comment: In my routine -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation, I had conditionals set on whether I would allow rotation to a new orientation.  I had a bug where I didn't allow any orientation.  So I added a base condition to always allow portrait at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RESOLVED OK. I finally found the problem here. Again this only appeared in iOS5 but when my RootViewController launches it holds off on rotations until the animation is done. Once it is done, then it allows rotations again. The problem was that it was returning NO for all aspects (including portrait). The view showed fine but when I would present a modal and return, the view geometry was mangled. Once I changed it to return YES for portrait mode even during animation, the problem went away.